# i need to display the selected table from the dropdown, with their respective column names and number of fields using jsp and AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsp, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

****in my code the drop down contain many tables name which are there in database. each table column names and the number of columns are different from other tables. if i select any table name from drop down it should display the whole table with their respective column names and number of fields****

// in my first jspfile

```
function showCustomer(str)
{
var xmlhttp;    
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","report3.jsp?ID="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

REPORT:  <select name="ID" onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">

                <option value="infoo">INFOO</option>
                <option value="attendence">ATTENDENCE</option>
                <option value="customerdetail">CUSTOMERDETAIL</option>
                <option value="billingdetail">BILLINGDETAIL</option>

            </select><br/>
            <br/>
          </font><div id="txtHint"></div>

// in the next file report3.jsp

String ID=request.getParameter("ID");
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ ID +"");

%>

<table border="1" bordercolor="#2494b7">
<tr>
<th></th>

<th></th>

<th></th>

<th></th>

<th></th>

</tr>
<%
while(rs.next())
{
    %>

<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>

<td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>

<td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
<tr/>

<%

}
%>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the respective column names and number of fields/row of your table, you can use [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

```
 String s = rsmd.getColumnLabel(int column);
 //Gets the designated column's suggested title for use in printouts and displays.
```

OR

```
 String s = rsmd.getColumnName(int column);
 // Get the designated column's name.
```

Use it like this for header and same for rows:

Edited **Not Tested**:

```
<%

ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ ID +"");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();


  int cnt = rsmd.getColumnCount()
  for(int i =1;i<=cnt;i++){
  %>
   <th><%=rsmd.getColumnLabel(1)%></th>
  <%
   }
   while(rs.next()){
   for(int i =1;i<=cnt;i++){
      String type = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i);
      if(type.equals("String")|| type.equals("string")){
   %> 
     <td><%=rs.getString(i)%></td>
   <%
    }else{   // or countinue else if (check for other data types based on your database)
   %>
        <td><%=rs.getInt(i)%></td> 
   <%
    }
   } 
  }
  %>
```

Probably you got the idea.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html

Comment: error in line "String s = rsmd.getColumnName(int column);". (Syntax error on token "int", delete this token).. i tried declaring column in all ways.. please hep me to solve this

Comment: Meghna, it is method description ,which says to get the columnName for specified column. For eg. if you want to get the name of first column of database then code will be String s = rsmd.getColumnName(1) ;

Comment: Happy to help, please accept the answer, if your problem is solved.